# Extracting ones age from wikipedia

Tags: r, regex, html-encode

I would like to take my current data frame of nfl players and search for their age on wikipedia. I currently have this function built that loops through the names in my data frame and replaces the space between the first and last name with a '_'. I then use the 'rvest' library to read the html code of the website and extract the infobox.

The problem with my current loop is the object age_row where I filter the list to search for 'Born'.

If you would like me to add more information please let me know and I will edit the post.

P.S. I usually work with data frames and rarely touch large nested list...

Thank you in advance.

```
getwiki <- function(name){
  for(i in RB_14_22$Player){
    NewName <- gsub(' ','_', i)
    Link <- paste0('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/',NewName)
    url <- URLencode(Link)
    page <- read_html(url)
    # Extract the infobox from the page
    infobox <- page %>% html_nodes(".infobox") %>% html_table()
    # Extract the row containing the person's age
    age_row <- infobox[[1]] %>%
      filter(grepl("Born", .)) %>% 
      filter(grepl("age", .))
    # Extract the age value from the age row
    age <- age_row[[1, 2]] %>% 
      str_extract("\\d+")
    # Print the person's age
    cat("The person's age is:", age, "\n")
  }
}
```

head of infobox[[1]] is...

```
# A tibble: 6 × 14
  X1                           X2             X3    X4    X5       X6 X7       X8 X9      X10 X11   X12   X13     X14
  <chr>                        <chr>          <chr> <chr> <chr> <dbl> <chr> <int> <chr> <int> <chr> <chr> <chr> <int>
1 McCaffrey in 2019            McCaffrey in … NA    NA    NA       NA NA       NA NA       NA NA    NA    NA       NA
2 No. 23 – San Francisco 49ers No. 23 – San … NA    NA    NA       NA NA       NA NA       NA NA    NA    NA       NA
3 Position:                    Running back   NA    NA    NA       NA NA       NA NA       NA NA    NA    NA       NA
4 Personal information         Personal info… NA    NA    NA       NA NA       NA NA       NA NA    NA    NA       NA
5 Born:                        (1996-06-07) … NA    NA    NA       NA NA       NA NA       NA NA    NA    NA       NA
6 Height:                      5 ft 11 in (1… NA    NA    NA       NA NA       NA NA       NA NA    NA    NA       NA
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a complete example that may help. After filtering where first column value contains "Born" and `pull`ing the second column (which contains the information of interest), you may need to remove hidden characters after scraping. Viewing the web page source, there is a `&#160` numeric entity reference (intended to be parseable by machines) between "age" and the numeric age value. Below I used `str_replace_all` to replace anything not parentheses or alphanumeric character with empty space for now.

Then, you can use `str_extract` with a regex look-behind for "age" followed by a numeric value for the age itself.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)

NewName <- "Christian_McCaffrey"

Link <- paste0('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/', NewName)
page <- read_html(URLencode(Link))

infobox <- page %>% 
  html_nodes(".infobox") %>% 
  html_table()

infobox[[1]] %>%
  filter(grepl("Born", .[[1]])) %>%
  pull(2) %>%
  str_replace_all("[^\\(|\\)|[:alnum:]]", " ") %>%
  str_extract("(?<=age) \\d+") %>%
  as.numeric
```

**Output**

```
[1] 26
```

Or without replacing any characters, but just with `str_extract` alone and using the unicode `\u00A0` for the numeric entity reference, you could try:

```
infobox[[1]] %>%
  filter(grepl("Born", .[[1]])) %>%
  pull(2) %>%
  str_extract("(?<=age)\u00A0\\d+")
```